# FTP Explicit fails on celluar data

Tags: java, ssl, ftp

This question is a followup of [this original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183715/ftp-explicit-fails-to-connect-on-android-using-apache-ftpsclient-on-cellular-dat). After settling with FTP implicit for a while, I again decided to look into the issue. This time, I wrote a simple FTP client in pure java (non-android) and analyzed the SSL/TLS debug messages as I connected to the internet via my phone's hotspot.

The problem occurs during the TLS handshake right after ClientHello has been sent. FTP-wise, this corresponds to right after `AUTH TLS` was successfully accepted by the server. The failed exchange is denoted as follows:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1416712655 bytes = { <binary data> }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=<server>]
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 188
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
main, called close()
```

For reference, a successful exchange is included below:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1416713014 bytes = { <binary data> }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=<server>]
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 188
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 81
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 142326665 bytes = { <binary data> }
Session ID:  { <session id data> }
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
```

I've tried using TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1 and all resulted in the same result, where the socket times out and the server closing the connection. The FTP server (FileZilla Server 0.9.48 beta) offers no detailed log of the issue.

Any insight on the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that traffic "optimization" at your provider causes the problems. Deep packet inspection to "optimize" traffic is very common for cellular networks and is often used to improve the traffic and sometimes also used to block unwanted traffic.

How this relates to your problem:
Within cellular networks usually NAT is needed, that is you don't get a public IP address. But, at least the active mode in FTP needs a public IP and thus it is not uncommon to employ helper programs which translate IP and port for the PORT/EPRT commands inside the FTP control connection. These helper programs are not able to work with encrypted connections, which means they either block such connections on purpose or might block them by accident because they don't understand the traffic anymore.

Comment: All communications in my scenario run under passive mode FTP (`PASV` or `EPSV` command is sent prior each data retrieving/store command). Also, implicit FTP seems to work just fine. What I don't get is why the same TLS exchange seems to fail in explicit when it works without issue in implicit.

Comment: It does not matter if you use passive or active mode, because there is no way to inform intercepting devices up-front that you will use passive mode inside the encrypted connection. And the difference between implicit and explicit TLS is that the explicit uses the same port as plain FTP and thus is affected by the helper application. Implicit instead uses another port which probably is not intercepted by the provider because there would be no way to rewrite the PORT/EPRT commands anyway.

Comment: After additional tests, what you say seems reasonable. Still baffles me how they can just block traffic like this (I live in a area where internet traffic is quite open, no filtering or whatever).

Comment: I don't think that this is intentionally blocking. I think that they are trying to be helpful so that active FTP works, but then inadvertently block explicit FTPS because of a buggy helper software. If they would be intentionally block FTPS then the would block implicit FTPS too and block the `AUTH TLS` command instead of just failing to deal with binary data (TLS Client Hello) on the connection.

Comment: From a short look at ftp-proxy from OpenBSD it looks like that it least this helper would cause the same problems, but other helpers probably too. And since FTPS is actually quite rare it is probably better for most users if they have no trouble with plain FTP (i.e. that active mode works) even if some users suffer because FTPS fails.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Oh well... Stuck with implicit FTP then. Not that there is any issue with it (when its properly used), just the fact that its depreciated discourages use.